# Value of a ComboBox within a QGroupBox (in a form) by using PyQt5

Tags: qgis, pyqt5, combo-box

In QGIS3 I would like to get the current form-value of a ComboBox, that is within a QGroupBox (in the form).

I would like to get that value by using PyQt5.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Hi Kai, can you add a little bit more context what you will be using the value for. This will help to give you an appropriate answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you very much. I found a solution just 1 minute before. I will poste it soon...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it.
Be careful, that you don't try get the `ComboBox` of your form by an alias you set before.

Without the alias it works:

```
meineComboBOX = myDialog.findChild(QComboBox, "ID_UTILISATION")
```

and then e.g. `meineComboBOX.currentData()` or `meineComboBOX.currentText()`.